# Show top 10 scores for a game using DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, scalability

I created a table "scores" in DynamoDB to store the scores of a game.

The table has the following attributes:

- uuid
- username
- score
- datetime

Now I want to query the "top 10" scores for the game (leaderboard).

In DynamoDB, it is not possible to create an index without a partition key.

So, how do I perform this query in a scalable manner?

Comment: Unfortunately, Dynamodb doesn't support this use case.

Comment: Its possible. Just need a sort key on score.

Comment: But how can I add a sort key without a partition key?

Answer (score 2):

No.  You will always need the partition key.  DynamoDB is able to provide the required speed at scale because it stores records with the same partition key *physically* close to each other instead of on 100 different disks (or SSDs, or even servers).

If you have a mature querying use case (which is what DynamoDB was designed for) e.g. "Top 10 *monthly* scores" then you can hash **datetime** into a derived **month** attribute like 12/01/2017, 01/01/2018, and so on and then use this as your partition key so all the scores generated in the same month will get "bucketized" into the same partition for the best lookup performance.  You can then keep **score** as the sort key.

You can of course have other tables (or LSIs) for weekly and daily scores.  Or you can even choose the most granular bucket and sum up the results yourself in your application code.  You'll prob need to pull a lot more then 10 records to get *close enough* to 100% accuracy on the aggregate level... I don't know.  Test it.  I wouldn't rely on it if I were dealing with money/commissions but for game scores who cares :)

Note: If you decide to use this route then instead of using "12/10/2017" etc. as the partition values I'd use integer offsets e.g. UNIX epoch (rounded off to represent the first midnight of the month) to make it easier to compute/code against.  I used the friendly dates to better illustrate the approach.

Comment: Good explanation. In case I want a "ALL TIME TOP SCORES", I think I can create ANOTHER table, with a DUMMY partition key (eg.: all values set to the same partition) but have my application to insert in this table ONLY when the new score is greater than the 10th best score. And periodically delete scores lower than the 10th. That way, although all items will be in the same partition, the table will never have much more than 10 items, and so it will solve the scalability issue. Correct?

Comment: Just got home and really sat down and read your comment.  I thought you were asking about getting top 1 score instead of 10.  Yes, your approach should work for that case

Comment: I'm having the same issue to create a leaderboard using dynamoDB.
I just need all time top 10 score.
I have a similar table.
But no query is working for me.